# How to change Chromes media device API

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, directshow, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to acces a webcam through WebRTC in Chrome.

Everything works on most PCs but on some it just shows a black screen.
Drivers and everything is installed and a little test program from the webcam manufacturer shows a video stream on all PCs.

In Chrome under chrome://media-internals you can look up some information about the media devices used in chrome.
On the PCs, that show a valid video stream, Chrome is using Direct Show as the device API. On the PCs, that show a black screen, Chrome is using Media Foundation as the device API.

How can I change the device API Chrome is using to acces the webcam?

Comment: This seems hardware related, not about programming. There's just one WebRTC API for all devices (emphasis on 'web'). Unless you're attempting to fix Chrome by building a custom version of Chromium? If so, please include more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome recently switched to MediaFoundation for capture, see the comments in
 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=849636#c10
about how to test whether that particular camera works or not. If it does not work with MediaFoundation you should file a bug specifying the camera model so it can be blacklisted. Trying the same camera in Firefox on https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/ might give an indication about the model.

Comment: I will try it with Firefox and with the -disable-MediaFoundation tag on monday. But the PCs on which the webcam is working on, are running the same version of Chrome. I doublechecked that.

Comment: Thanks, the disable-feature=MediaFoundationVideoCapture flag helped.

Comment: Can you gather more information about the device (manifacturer, model name) and file a bug at crbug.com please? That sounds like the device needs to be blacklisted. Please post a link to the bug here.

Comment: in particular a screenshot of chrome://media-internals when it works.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=910044&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified